# Doing an modal logic exercise. The tableau for both the argument and its negation are open. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: logic, model-theory, modal-logic

I am doing an exercise from Graham Priest's textbook "An Introduction to Nonclassical Logic", and I think I'm doing something wrong. The exercise is to determine the validity of α=β, ◇Pα, ⊢ ◇Pβ. I am using constant domain modal logic. The lowercase Greek letters represent non-rigid descriptors, whereas lowercase Latin letters represent rigid designators. Capital letters represent predicates. The accessibility relation is the same as system K (so it is *not* reflexive, symmetrical, transitive, or Euclidean). My tableau is as follows:

1. α=β, 0
2. ◇Pα, 0
3. ¬◇Pβ, 0
4. α=a, 0             (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
5. β=b, 0             (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
6. a=β, 0             (Identity, 1, 4)
7. a=b, 0             (Identity, 5, 6)
8. □¬Pβ, 0            (¬◇, 3).
9. 0R1
   10.Pα, 1              (2, ◇)
10. α=c, 1            (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
11. ¬Pβ, 1            (8, □)
12. β=d, 1            (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
13. Pc, 1             (Identity, 10, 11)
14. ¬Pd, 1            (Identity, 12, 13)
15. a=b, 1            (Identity Invariance, 7)

I think that this tableau is correct and therefore this argument is invalid. However, I am a little confused because when I attempt to do a tableau of the same argument, except the conclusion is not negated, I am still left with an open tableau. Because the logic I am using has a classical metatheory, and thus bivalence and the law of excluded middle hold, shouldn't I end up with a closed tableau? Here is my tableau for the negation of the original problem in the textbook:

1. α=β, 0
2. ◇Pα, 0
3. ◇Pβ, 0
4. α=a, 0             (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
5. β=b, 0             (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
6. a=β, 0             (Identity, 1, 4)
7. a=b, 0             (Identity, 5, 6)
8. 0R1
9. Pα, 1              (◇, 2)
10. α=c, 1            (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
11. Pc, 1             (Identity, 9, 10)
12. 0R2
13. Pβ, 2             (◇, 3)
14. β=d, 2            (Assigning a rigid constant to descriptor)
15. Pd, 2             (Identity, 13, 14)
16. a=b, 1            (Identity invariance)
17. a=b, 2            (Identity invariance)

I must have made a mistake somewhere and one of these tableaus should close. Perhaps I misunderstand some of the rules of this logic. If anybody can show me where I have made a mistake I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

P.S. This is not homework, I am just refreshing myself on modal logic in preparation for further study in philosophy.

Comment: Can’t you go from $\Diamond P \alpha$, $a= \alpha$ to $\Diamond Pa$, and likewise for $\neg \Diamond P \beta$ and $b=\beta$ to set up a contradiction?

Comment: @PW_246, I think you may be right. However, I for some reason have the notion in my head that I can only substitute unbounded constants (if that makes sense). If this is the case, then I have to get rid of the modal operator before I substitute α for β. I may be wrong on this though. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The deduction is not valid.

Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not rigid descriptors, it could be that $\alpha=\beta$ in a world, but not in the accessible world where $P\alpha$ holds. So there is no reason to expect that $P\beta$ is possible. One can make a countermodel with two worlds, where $\alpha=\beta$ in the first world, but not in the second world, where $P\alpha$ holds and $P_\beta$ fails in all worlds.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been mentioned, it is not the case that $\alpha=\beta$ and $\lozenge P(\alpha)$ entail $\lozenge P(\beta)$. However, there is one more important point to address.

You ask

> I am a little confused because when I attempt to do a tableau of the same argument, except the conclusion is not negated, I am still left with an open tableau. Because the logic I am using has a classical metatheory, and thus bivalence and the law of excluded middle hold, shouldn't I end up with a closed tableau?

The answer to this is negative. It is perfectly possible in classical logic that a set of formulas $\Gamma$ does not entail a formula $\phi$, nor its negation $\neg\phi$. In fact, if there is no formula $\phi$ s.t. $\Gamma\not\models\phi$ and $\Gamma\not\models\neg\phi$, then $\Gamma$ is called a *complete theory*.

Of course, not every theory is complete: the simplest example is to take $\Gamma=\{\chi:\chi\text{ is valid}\}$ (or, equivalently, make $\Gamma$ empty) — in this case, $\Gamma\not\models P(\alpha)$ nor $\Gamma\not\models\neg P(\alpha)$ for any variable $\alpha$. There are other examples, e.g., $S(a)$ entails neither $Q(c)$ nor $\neg Q(c)$, etc. Similarly, $\{\alpha=\beta,\lozenge P(\alpha)\}$ is not complete.

A theory being incomplete does not contradict the law of excluded middle. This is because the entailment concerns *all models* (in all models where assumptions hold, the conclusion must also be true). On the other hand, the law of excluded middle says that in every model, either $\psi$ or $\neg\psi$ is true but, of course, does not say that any of them is true in all models.

Comment: and Professor Hamkins, Thank you so much for answering my quite rudimentary question. I know understand my misunderstanding!